# Measuring polyline lengths running through a raster - is this possible?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, line, length

I have a reclassified raster layer with 4 values and a vector layer of polylines. I would like to discover the length of the lines running through each raster value, or the percentage of the lines within each raster value.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible please?

I was informed Zonal Statistics may be able to do this, but to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: Using the Zonal Statistics method, did you convert your vector to a raster, and generate raster attribute table for both rasters?

Comment: Thanks - No, i did it Vesctor lines vs Raster. Is Raster vs Raster the only way i could get something reasonable? I would be happy with a % figure of the polyline in the raster, if possible?

Comment: With some obvious exceptions, all raster operations in ArcGIS are, ultimately, raster-on-raster calculations.  The apparent ability to do zonal stats with vector features is merely a front-end convenience: ArcGIS will rasterize those features in order to carry out the computation.  (The exceptions are calculations whose nature clearly prohibits an initial vector-to-raster conversion; *e.g.*, you can request interpolated values at specific point locations; to do that, ArcGIS must use the actual location rather than a one-cell approximation to it.)

Answer (score 3):

You could turn your raster into a polygon then run an intersect with this polygon layer with your line layer.

Comment: Thanks - i am hesitant, as one of my next raster layers has many small raster areas (approx 100 areas) , which i'm concerned will make the situation very confusing. Do you think this would be confusing, or manageable?